# Proper way to call object values from prototype?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So I've got an object that is created a few hundred times, and I am using the prototype in order to update them all, each with their own different values. However I believe I am calling the object incorrectly, as it cannot access any of the object's values.

```
var asteroids = [];

//Create some objects
for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
    asteroids[i] = new Asteroid();
}

function Asteroid() {
    this.x = Math.random();
    this.y = Math.random();
};

//Used to update each object
Asteroid.prototype.update = function() {
    this.x += Math.random();
    this.y += Math.random();
};

//Updates all the objects by calling the prototype each second
setInterval(function() {
    Asteroid.prototype.update();
},1000);
```

I receive an error on the prototype saying it cannot get the value "x", so what is the proper way to use it in order to update all of the objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to perform the `update()` operation on an *instance* of `Asteroid`:

```
// Updates all the objects by calling the prototype each second
setInterval(function() {
    asteroids.forEach(function(a) { a.update(); });
}, 1000);
```

Calling the `Asteroid.prototype.update()` does not call the `update` method on all instances of `Asteroid`.

---

**Further Reading**

- [MDN reference for `Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thanks for help! Works just as I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Calling the function attached to the prototype will NOT apply it on all instances. It is just a function. You need to iterate over your array and invoke the update() on every object.